# Ruby pass arguments from one function to another function

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, parameter-passing, haml

I am calling an onclick function in haml to my ruby controller:

```
%button.btn.btn-danger{:type => "button", onclick: "select_method_type("+bell.id.to_s+")"} ring
```

I want the argument of select_method_type to be passed into ringring_post method. How do do this ruby?

```rb
def select_method_type
    if @bell.request_type == "POST"
      ringring_post
    else
      ringring_get
    end
  end
```

Comment: Is `select_method_type` going to be called in js or on backend during render?

Comment: @Vasfed the later would require a time machine?

Comment: @max a powerful sorcerer might suffice for that :) Actually, we cannot be sure if `select_method_type` is a js function, a ruby method or (most probably) both

Comment: Your question is unclear. `select_method_type` doesn't take any arguments, so what is there to forward?

Comment: im writing in ruby. select_method_type should be in ruby

Comment: yes select_method_type does not take args but it was present same like before. I want to keep it that way only. it is some ruby implicit way of passing id of elements

Comment: just add a parameter and use that in your ringring_get function, or am I missing something?